# Pandas - Strange issue with datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a strange issue with a Datetime column.
Suppose there is a date in a start_date column:

```python
>>> df2.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 641 entries, 9 to 1394
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   number      641 non-null    object        
 1   start_date  641 non-null    datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
memory usage: 15.0+ KB
```

When I set the index to start_date, DatetimeIndex seems to be incomplete:

```python
>>> df2 = df2.set_index('start_date')
>>> df2.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 641 entries, 2020-01-01 to 2020-03-01
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   number  641 non-null    object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 10.0+ KB
```

Actually there are more entries in this dataframe:

```python
df3 = df2.copy()
df3 = df3.reset_index()
df3 = df3[pd.to_datetime(df3['start_date']).dt.month > 3]
df3 = df3.set_index('start_date')
df3.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 393 entries, 2020-04-01 to 2020-09-01
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   number  393 non-null    object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 6.1+ KB
```

As you can see, there are entries with a date up to `2020-09-01`. But why are these dates only sometimes given? I could not detect a gap or something similar in the index start_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `DataFrame.info` prints out the `XXX to YYY` information from the index it simply prints out the value of the first index value to the value of the last index value. **If your index is not monotonic** (can easily check with `df.index.is_monotonic`) this doesn't correspond to the full span.

The code responsible for this is [`Index._summary`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.3/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L997-L1019), and it's clear it's simply looking at the first value `[0]` and last value `[-1]` when it summarizes

```
def _summary(self, name=None) -> str_t:
    """
    Return a summarized representation.
    Parameters
    ----------
    name : str
        name to use in the summary representation
    Returns
    -------
    String with a summarized representation of the index
    """
    if len(self) > 0:
        head = self[0]
        if hasattr(head, "format") and not isinstance(head, str):
            head = head.format()
        tail = self[-1]
        if hasattr(tail, "format") and not isinstance(tail, str):
            tail = tail.format()
        index_summary = f", {head} to {tail}"
    else:
        index_summary = ""
```

---

Here's a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,1,1], index=pd.to_datetime(['2010-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2011-01-01']))

df.info()

#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#DatetimeIndex: 3 entries, 2010-01-01 to 2011-01-01
#...
```

If you want the full range `sort` the index before looking at the info:

```
df.sort_index().info()
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#DatetimeIndex: 3 entries, 2010-01-01 to 2012-01-01
#...
```